# Two binary strings are given which has "-" and "+". If - and - equals + , we have to find if 1st string can be converted into second

Tags: python-3.x, string

Ouput should be Yes if its possible to convert string

```
   def string_can_be_converted(a, b):
        i = 0
        s = ""
        while i < len(a) - 1:
            if (i == len(a) - 1) or (a[i] == "-" and a[i + 1] == "-"):
                if (i == len(a) - 1):
                    s += a[i]
                else:
                    s += "+"
                    i+=2
            else:
                s += a[i]
                i+=1   
        if s == b:
            return "Yes"
        else:
            return "No " + s
```

input:

```
z = "--++----+"
f = "++++++"
```

the output should be Yes but I am doing something wrong

```
print(number_of_reduction(z, f))
```

output:

```
No +++++
```

Comment: As your output is one less + than it should be, the natural suspicion would be that you are not considering the last character. Which is the case, yes.

Comment: Also if we consider "---" vs. "-+", your approach would fail anyway. You should probably traverse a and b at the same time and try to match them incrementally.

Comment: This is not defined well, since, for example `---` can be converted to `+-` and to `-+`.

Comment: I think "can it be" is well-defined enough => "does there exist a sequence of reductions". But it won't work with a greedy approach OP appears to be using.

Comment: What is the criteria for "can be converted"? If you can convert both ``--`` -> ``+`` and ``+`` -> ``--``, it seems sufficient to compare the length of both strings in "base ``--``". That is just ``len(a.replace('+', '--')) == len(b.replace('+', '--'))``. Performing the actual or even optimal conversion seems not required.

Comment: Or to rephrase that: Is ``-+-+`` equivalent to ``+++``, since ``- + - +`` -> ``- -- - --`` -> ``-- -- --`` -> ``+ + +``? ``--`` equals ``+`` implies that, since it means ``+`` equals ``--``.

Comment: I don't think it's meant to be symmetric, but this could use a clarification from OP. (OP's attempted solution is definitely not symmetric)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def string_can_be_converted(a, b):
    return '+'.join(a.split('--')) == b

z = '--++----+'
f = '++++++'
print(string_can_be_converted(z, f))
```

Comment: for counterexample see comments above

Comment: @dratenik: Yes, one of them being my own comment. Under the current definition, I think it's the best that can be achieved (meaning, if the current definition is "fine tuned", then this solution will likely hold for it).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both '+-' and '-+' are valid conversions for '---', the solution could look something like this:

```
def string_can_be_converted(a,b):
    if (a == b): return True
    if (a == '' or b ==''): return False
    if (a[0] == b[0]):
        return string_can_be_converted(a[1:], b[1:])
    if (a.startswith('--') and b.startswith('+')):
        return string_can_be_converted(a[2:], b[1:])
    return False
```